# html - Header size wider than the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making an html web page and I have this problem: The header of my page is wider than my screen size, causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear. I already check some solutions, but they didn't work. Can anyone know why this is happening?

here is my header code:

```
<header>
    <!--NAV BAR-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top elegant-color-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- NAV BRAND-->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="http://eprticher.mx/images/tich.gif" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top mr-2" alt="">
            TICHER | Seguridad Privada
        </a>

        <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Servicios</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="dropMenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicios_seguridad.html">Servicios Seguridad</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="tranp_ejecutiva.html">Transporte Ejecutivo</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="quienes_somos.html">¿Quienes Somos?</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="porque_elegirnos.html">¿Porqué Elegirnos?</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contactanos.html">Contáctanos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
body {
background-color: #ffffff;
padding-top: 60px;
}

header {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sizeAdj img {
 width: auto;
 height: 500px;
 max-height: 500px;
}

.img-resp {
 width: 100%;
}

.img-resp-sm {
 width: 50%;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40%;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 25;
  /*background: rgb(68, 68, 68);*/
  color: white;
 }

.separator {
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
 }
```

The Header CSS is a solution that I found but it looks like it doesn't works...

[Snapshot of the problem...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyRzo.jpg)

Here is how I add the Header to another HTML File where I use it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
<title>TICHER | Estrategias de Protección</title>
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#header").load("header.html");
        $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--HEADER-->
<div id="header"></div>

<!--MAIN-->
<main class="mt-5 mb-5"> 
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="mb-5 mt-5 font-weight-bold text-center">¿Quienes Somos?</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6  mr-5">
               <p class="grey-text font-bold text-justify"> 
                   <strong>TICHER</strong> nace con una experiencia de mas de 30 años en las áreas de <strong>Administración de Personal y Seguridad</strong>. 
                   El enfoque de la empresa es dar servicios que coadyuven al logro de los objetivos del cliente y atender a los diferentes sectores del mercado.
                   Para ello dentro de nuestra filosofía se encuentra privilegiar la atención y la respuesta oportuna, para cubrir las necesidades del cliente.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md">
                <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight z-depth-1-half text-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-resp" src="img/SignificadoLetras.jpg" alt="">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="mask"></div>
                    </a>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<!--Footer-->
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<!--Google Maps-->
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you also using Material Design CSS? Have you already included the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)?

Comment: @showdev Yes, I load the header using JavaScript. In the other html document I have the meta tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: I'm having trouble [reproducing the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/eh9x3y8b/).

Comment: @showdev I load the header HTML to another HTML file, in the other files I have all the <links> with the css and js. Maybe thats why the header doesnt creates as it needs to be in your simulation..
I added an snapshot, in there you can see the problem. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following css, and it should fix the horizontal scrollbar issue

```
body .navbar-nav{
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```css
body .navbar-nav{
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}

body {
background-color: #ffffff;
padding-top: 60px;
}

header {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;
}



.sizeAdj img {
 width: auto;
 height: 500px;
 max-height: 500px;
}

.img-resp {
 width: 100%;
}

.img-resp-sm {
 width: 50%;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40%;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 25;
  /*background: rgb(68, 68, 68);*/
  color: white;
 }

.separator {
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top elegant-color-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- NAV BRAND-->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="http://eprticher.mx/images/tich.gif" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top mr-2" alt="">
            TICHER | Seguridad Privada
        </a>

        <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Servicios</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="dropMenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicios_seguridad.html">Servicios Seguridad</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="tranp_ejecutiva.html">Transporte Ejecutivo</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="quienes_somos.html">¿Quienes Somos?</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="porque_elegirnos.html">¿Porqué Elegirnos?</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contactanos.html">Contáctanos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
```

Comment: You are still getting h scrollbars? If so, could you show a snapshot?

Comment: I already added the snapshot to the problem description. In the snapshot I slided the scroll bar to the right to show that the body of the page has the right size and the header is the one that is bigger than the screen..

Comment: I think the problem is caused by other elements in your page. Are you able to provide more of it? At least in fiddle code?

Comment: I am having a hard time using the html you provide to produce the issue you are facing. At least, will you at least be able to have your issue reproducible on Fiddle or CodePen? I am pretty sure that the problem is related to container-fluid and/or row styles, but I need to be able to debug the problem on a working page.

Comment: You where right, it was a problem with a typo in a container but in the Footer, thanks!